# An example of nonzero ring $R$ with $R^m\cong R^n$, $m\neq n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'd like to find an example of a nonzero ring $R$ and positive integers $m,n$ with $m\neq n$ such that $R^m\cong R^n$ as $R$-modules.

Comment: Any conditions for the ring? Can it be the zero ring?

Comment: @B.Swan nope, I reedit the question

Comment: See example 1.4 here https://books.google.iq/books?id=6iLUBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR1&dq=lectures%20on%20rings%20and%20modules&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For commutative rings with one this does not happen. For a non-commutative example take $R = \text{End}_K(K[X])$ for a field $K$. Then $R$ is a free $R$-module with basis $\{\text{id}_{K[X]}\}$. Now consider
$$f_1(X^n) := \begin{cases} X^{n/2} &\mbox{if $n$ is even}, \\ 0 &\mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and
$$f_2(X^n) := \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if $n$ is even}, \\ X^{(n-1)/2} &\mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
Then $\{f_1, f_2\}$ is also a basis of $R$, i.e. $R \simeq R^2$. Inductively we see $R \simeq R^n$.

Comment: Why can't it happen in commutative rings with $1$?  Let $V=\{f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb Q \}$ with addition and multiplication defined pointwise.  Isn't it the case that $V$ is a $\Bbb Q$-module and that $V \cong V^2$ as $\Bbb Q$-modules?

Comment: There is no integer $n$ with $V = \mathbb{Q}^n$. And the correct formulation would actually be: Over commutative rings with unity, the cardinality of a basis of a free module is well-defined.